# How to make calls with council origin?

Tags: pallet

In the tests of a pallet, I would like to use the council as the origin.

I did the following:

1. Imported the collective pallet
2. Implemented `pallet_collective::Config` for `Test`:

```rs
type CouncilCollective = pallet_collective::Instance1;
impl pallet_collective::Config<CouncilCollective> for Test {
    type RuntimeOrigin = RuntimeOrigin;
    type Proposal = RuntimeCall;
    type RuntimeEvent = RuntimeEvent;
    type MotionDuration = MotionDuration;
    type MaxProposals = MaxProposals;
    type MaxMembers = MaxMembers;
    type DefaultVote = pallet_collective::PrimeDefaultVote;
    type WeightInfo = ();
}
```

3. Set the `GenesisConfig`:

```rs
    pallet_collective::GenesisConfig::<Test, Instance1> {
        members: vec![1, 2, 3],
        phantom: Default::default(),
    }
    .assimilate_storage(&mut t)
    .unwrap();
```

4. Wrote the test like this:

```rs
        // this returns a RuntimeCall that can be called by council
        let proposal = make_proposal() 
        let proposal_len: u32 = proposal.using_encoded(|p| p.len() as u32);
        let proposal_weight = proposal.get_dispatch_info().weight;
        let hash = BlakeTwo256::hash_of(&proposal);

        assert_ok!(Council::propose(
            RuntimeOrigin::signed(1),
            3,
            Box::new(proposal.clone()),
            proposal_len
        ));

        assert_ok!(Council::vote(RuntimeOrigin::signed(1), hash, 0, true));
        assert_ok!(Council::vote(RuntimeOrigin::signed(2), hash, 0, true));
        assert_ok!(Council::vote(RuntimeOrigin::signed(3), hash, 0, true));

        System::set_block_number(4);
        assert_ok!(Council::close(
            RuntimeOrigin::signed(4),
            hash,
            0,
            proposal_weight,
            proposal_len
        ));

        // The test fails at this assertion, the result is not Ok   
        System::assert_last_event(RuntimeEvent::Council(pallet_collective::Event::Executed {
            proposal_hash: hash,
            result: Ok(()),
        }));
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Did you checked what events are being present?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to execute something using the council origin, you can construct it on your own:

```
Pallet::run_whatever(pallet_collective::RawOrigin::Members(5, 5).into(), args);
```

Comment: Yeah, this is a much simpler approach, thanks!