# How to call with `pallet_collective::RawOrigin` within another pallet's benchmarks

Tags: pallet-collective

I'm struggling to benchmark my extrinsics that are called by the [`pallet_collective::RawOrigin`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/713e34ae960d122519093c9015f64c4afd74aa53/frame/collective/src/lib.rs#L139). I found [this](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/5442/how-to-make-calls-with-council-origin) answer that got me close:

```
let origin: <T as frame_system::Config>::RuntimeOrigin = pallet_collective::RawOrigin::Members(condoned, total).into();
#[extrinsic_call]
_(origin, Box::new(call));
```

However, I get the error message:
[image]

I found [this post](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/7784/substrate-poa-and-validator-set-and-pallet-collection-configuration-error-the-tr) which looks very similar however I included pallet_collective in the mock runtime (`Instance1`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of the origin is never used, so in order to construct the call you just need *any* instance that will pass the `ensure_origin` filter.

This can be achieved by using the `try_successful_origin` of the origin type itself to provide a valid instance. You can create such an origin like this:

```rust
let origin =
    <T as Config>::SimpleMajorityOrigin::try_successful_origin()
    .map_err(|_| BenchmarkError::Weightless)?;
```

This in total will not work *quite* yet, but there is a custom syntax in the V2 that can be used to coerce the type such that the call becomes:

```rust
#[extrinsic_call]
_(origin as T::RuntimeOrigin, Box::new(call));
```

Note that the `pallet_collective` is not needed at all in this case, since it would be an implementation detail of the runtime developer of how to provide a concrete `SimpleMajorityOrigin` type.